# get div id when an object is dropped using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the div id of the dragged item when it is dropped to a div. 
My problem is , when I drop it into the layer 3, it also reads the layer 1 and layer 2.
What I want is only the layer 3 since it is hovered.

Please consider the code below.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div>

<img class="item" src="img.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="layer1" class="droppable" style="width:100px; height : 100px ;">
 <div id="layer2" class="droppable" style="width:70px; height : 70px; ">
  <div id="layer3" class="droppable" style="width:50px; height: 50px">
           Drop an image here    </div>
  </div>
</div>    
<script>
$(function(){
 $(".droppable").droppable({ accept : 'item' , drop : Calldropp });    
 function Calldropp (){
    <!-- what to do here -->
  }

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$(function(){
    $(".droppable").droppable({ accept : 'item' , drop : Calldropp });    
    function Calldropp (event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

This should stop the dropping propagation at the most inner element.